# How can I use Knockout's click binding with jQuery Mobile's vclick event?

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

In my jQuery Mobile + Knockout.js application all clicks have the [300ms delay](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/faq/how-do-i-use-touch-mouse-events.php) before the synthesized 'click' event fires.

Is trying to use jQM's 'vclick' event the right way to address this? If so, how can I accomplish that with the knockout click binding? Should I be using 'tap' instead?

Comment: You could use the `event` binding instead of `click`, like this: `data-bind="event: { vclick : your_handler }"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [fab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664108/fab) says, the way to do this is with knockout's `event` binding:

```
<!-- ko foreach: widgets -->
<li>
    <a data-bind="event: { vclick: $root.clickWidget }">
        <b data-bind="text: $data.name"></b>
    </a>
</li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Thanks!